# I can't use RandomForest inside a loop?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random-forest

I'm trying to get the optimal value of RandomForest parameters, which is why I used this loop:

'''
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

```
train_f1 = []
test_f1 = []

for i in range(10,100,10):
    
    clf=RandomForestCLassifier(min_samples_split=i)
    clf.fit(x_train2, y_train2)
  
    temp = clf.predict(x_train2)
    temp = f1_score(tmp,y_train2)
    train_f1.append(temp)

    tmp = clf.predict(x_valid)
    tmp = f1_score(tmp,y_valid)
    test_f1.append(tmp)
```

However, I got this error : "name 'RandomForestCLassifier' is not defined". I don't know what this error is talking about. Can someone please help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Check your capitalization.

Comment: RandomForestClassifier (3 capital letters, yours has 4)

Comment: @dm2 Thanks lol. I need to pay more attention

Comment: Happens to everyone, just need to learn what to look for. I'm sure you'll check this next time you get a similar error :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to import `RandomForestCLassifier` from scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

(Edit) you are misspelling `RandomForestClassifier`, the `L` should be lowercased.